# C++ STL - Why treat a function that returns an iterator as a void function?

Tags: c++, c++14

The STL has many functions that return iterators. For example, the STL list function erase returns an iterator (both C++98 and C++11). Nevertheless, I see it being used as a void function. Even the cplusplus.com site has an example that contains the following code:

```
mylist.erase(it1, it2);
```

which does not return an iterator. Shouldn't the proper syntax be as follows?

```
std::list<int>::iterator iterList = mylist.erase(it1, it2)?
```

Comment: If you don't care for the return type why store it?

Comment: you can always ignore the return if you arent going to use it. Also we would use `auto` these days :)

Comment: Not all professors allow students to use "auto." They need to test us on how well we understand types.

Comment: I guess you never wrote `cout << "hello";` then -- the `<<` returns a value and you didn't use it. You could write `std::ostream& x = cout << "hello";` , I doubt anyone would consider that "proper syntax".

Comment: @M.M actually that was the first example that came to my mind. In general when a function is designed for chaining, then you always have to ignore the last returned value

Comment: @Linda_980: Actually, one of the reasons we've added `auto` is because we understand the limitations on knowing types. For instance, we don't know the name of the return type of `std::bind( )` - we just know how to _use_ that type. Similarly, with iterators we know how to use them (`*` and `++`), regardless of the name.

Answer (score 8):

You are not forced to use a return value in C++. Normally the returned iterator should  be useful to have a new valid iterator to that container. But syntactically it's correct. Just keep in mind that after the erasure, `it1` and `it2` will not be valid any more.

Comment: Actually, `std::list` is somewhat special, for that specific container, `it2` will remain valid.

Comment: C++ allows us to do a variety of things that are not syntactically correct--if the program run, it does not mean that the code is correct. The rule is that if a function is declared as returning a value, it **must** return a value. So, "ignoring" that the function returns a value does not seem like a good choice. I thought there was a more valid reason, perhaps related to the STL.

Comment: What do you mean? You have often behaviour that is against the current C++ standard? If that's the case, you should open a bug to your compiler's bug report system. If it compiles, it is normally syntactically correct. Semantically they could be totally wrong anyway.

Comment: Actually ignoring the return type of a function has also a name: it's one _discarded-value expression_

Comment: @Linda_980: Yes, a function that says it will return a value must actually return a value. That's completely distinct from whether or not the caller uses or cares about that value.

Answer (score 7):

> which does not return an iterator. Shouldn't the proper syntax be as
>   follows?

It does return an iterator, but just as with any other function you can ignore the returned value. If you just want to erase an element and dont care about the returned iterator, then you may simply ignore it.

Actually ignoring the return value is more common than you might expect. Maybe the most common place where return values are ignored is when the only purpose of the return value is to enable chaining. For example the assignment operator is usually written as

```
Foo& operator=(const Foo& other){
    /*...*/
    return *this;
}
```

so that you can write something like `a = b = c`. However, when you only write `b = c` you usually ignore the value returned by that call. Also note, that when you write `b = c` this does return a value, but if you just want to make this assignment, then you have no other choice than to ignore the return value.

Answer (score 1):

The actual reason is far more banal than you might think. If you couldn't ignore a return value, many of the functions like `.erase()` would need to be split in two versions: an `.erase()` version returning `void` and another `.erase_and_return()` version which returned the iterator. What would you gain from this?

Comment: Well, my friend, there is [`std::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/ignore), or that appoach in general. But it would be very verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Return values are sometimes that are sometimes useful.  If they are not useful, you don't have to use them.

All `container.erase` functions return the iterator after the newly erased range.  For non-node-based containers this is often (but not always) useful because the iterators at and after the range are no longer valid.

For node-based containers this is usually useless, as the 2nd iterator passed in remains valid even after the erase operation.

Regardless, both return that iterator.  This permits code that works on a generic container to not have to know if the container maintains valid iterators after the erase or not; it can just store the return value and have a valid iterator to after-the-erase.

Iterators in C++ standard containers are all extremely cheap to create and destroy and copy; in fact, they are in practice so cheap that compilers can eliminate them entirely if they aren't used.  So returning an iterator that isn't used can have zero run time cost.

A program that doesn't use this return value here can be a correct program, both semantically and syntactically.  At the same time, other semantically and syntactically correct programs will require that you use that return value.

Finally,

```
mylist.erase(it1, it2);
```

this does return an iterator.  The iterator is immediately discarded (the return value only exists as an unnamed temporary), and compilers are likely to optimize it out of existence.

But just because you don't store a return value, doesn't mean it isn't returned.